# How to use py-requests in alpine linux docker?

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I built a python app that ran happily in its docker container until I added some http calls.. Using the library 'requests.' I did some research and alpine linux 3.7 has a library called 'py-requests'.. Only I can't seem to install this on my own system, to change my code to use it, and errors are thrown just leaving 'import requests' in my code. Py-pip doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Use `pip install requests` when building your image; have `requirements.txt` for Python your package.

Comment: Your question is really not clear. `Py-pip doesn't seem to work either`, this means you have install it using pip? `Only I can't seem to install this on my own system`, this means you have tried to install it, what's the command, what's the log if error? `to change my code to use it, and errors are thrown just leaving 'import requests' in my code`, what's the error? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 9000 and @atline 

I couldn't use pip install because I was blocked by a corporate firewall. I added --proxy mycompanyproxy.com:80 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org to my dockerfile's pip install command and was able to get what I needed. Thanks for commenting, and sorry for the vagueness, I am a noob :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use pip install because I was blocked by a corporate firewall. I added --proxy mycompanyproxy.com:80 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org to my dockerfile's pip install command and was able to get what I needed. Thanks for commenting, and sorry for the vagueness, I am a noob :)